# How to determine the depth of a term in a custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, dropdown, terms

I'm building a `<select>` dropdown to display a list of terms for a custom hierarchical taxonomy. How do I know the depth of each term? I'd like to add some indentation for child-terms (the more deeply they're nested, the more indentation there should be).

However I'm not able to retrieve the depth level from `get_terms()`. How to get the depth level as an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [wp_dropdown_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories):

> Display or retrieve the HTML dropdown list of categories.

```
$args = array(
    'show_count'   => 1,
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'taxonomy'     => 'my_taxonomy',
);

wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have a problem with this solution... what if I want to insert some onchange javascript in the <select> and put the term link in the <option> value? In this way the user would get redirected to the term archive by selecting the corresponding item in the list. wp_dropdown_categories() only outputs a plain list if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: uh... just thought of it, maybe I can create a custom walker for wp_dropdown_categories...

Comment: or even more practically, I could do this with javascript, just found a valid example in  codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories - apparently wp_dropdown_categories doesn't accept a custom walker in the args

Comment: But basically, your question has been answered? It would be nice if you could do the job with javascript.

Comment: there is some method descriped in http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories but URLs created with those methods will return 404 if one uses pretty permalinks, URL rewrites seem not to correct the problem (or maybe they work with blog posts only? in my case is a custom taxonomy)

Comment: It should work with custom taxonomy because there is a `taxonomy` argument you can provide. I tried to search for any clear code wich would explain where the url is build but I get stuck on [WP_Walker](http://phpdoc.wordpress.org/trunk/WordPress/Walker.html).

Comment: yeah I got stuck there too... there's a thing like Walker_CategoryDropdown, which is invoked by walk_category_dropdown_tree() which is inside wp_dropdown_categories().... too bad that the latter doesn't take an argument for a custom walker so one would have to rewrite everything just to pass a custom walker, doesn't seem logical to me. On the other hand what the other option would be? Store wp_dropdown_categories() into a variable and do a regex to alter the option contents?

Comment: what would be the way to perform a taxonomy query without permalinks? I tried myurl.com/?cat=<term_id> or myurl.com/?<taxonomy_name>=<term_id> they both return 404...

Comment: That definitely is an option, I probably should do the same thing now. Still wondering why there is no such option, it seems like a essential functionality since (i guess) most of the WordPress websites use Pretty Permalinks.

Comment: The normal category permalink structure is indeed `/?cat=1`, have you tried to display the category by displaying one trough the category menu?

Comment: I just realized that the options in the dropdown have a class assigned based on the depth. One could make some css rules to insert a padding for subcategories (which are .level-1 or higher number).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'hierarchical'  => true,
    'hide_empty' => false,
);
$the_query = new WP_Term_Query($args);
$categories = $the_query->get_terms();


foreach($categories as $cat){
    $ancestors = get_ancestors( $cat->term_id, 'category' );
    $cat->ancestors = $ancestors; // array( 0 => 15, 1 => 45 ) - 3rd level term
    $cat->depth = count( $ancestors ) ;
}
?>
<select>
    <?php 
        foreach($categories as $cat){
            echo '<option value="'.$cat->term_id.'">'.str_repeat('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;',$cat->depth).$cat->name.'</option>';
        } 
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your post, but would you please [edit it](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/272733/edit) and explain how this solves the OP's question.